# Order by relationship min max value Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent

I have Flights model and Terms model.

Term model has price column.

I want to sort the flights in order of their lowest term price.

In the fights model I have

```
public function terms()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Term');
}

public function termMinPrice()
{
    if($this->terms()->count() > 0){
        return $this->terms()->pluck('price')->min();
    } else{
        return 0;
    }
}
```

How do you order this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit Answer**
Try this

```
Flight::with('terms')->get()->sortByDesc('terms.price');
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I want to order flights, not terms

Comment: Modified the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Flight::with('terms')->get()->sortBy(function($flight) {
    return $flight->terms->min('price');
});
```